# Woocommerce: Creating a download link to product image

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Please have a look at my sample product page:
http://snshpl.com.sg/product/swa-8003-t/

I'm currently using hooks to hardcode the download button (together with a disclaimer text) to appear right after all my products' meta, this is the code added in my theme's functions.php:

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_meta_end','disclaimer');

function disclaimer(){
    echo '<br /><br /><a href="#" class="single_add_to_cart_button button     
    alt">Download</a><p id="disclaimer-text"><br /><br />*Color Disclaimer: 
    Due to the limitations of desktop scanners and the relative 
    inconsistencies of various display monitors, the colors you see on your 
    screen may not be a totally accurate reproduction of the actual product. 
    We strive to make our colors as accurate as possible, but screen images 
    are intended as a guide only and should not be regarded as absolutely 
    correct. If you would like to see a sample of any product shown on our 
    site, please call Customer Service at 6365 3383 or visit our contact 
    page.</p>';
}
```

My question is how do I extract the url of the image shown and add it to the link of the download button? I've tried various methods but not sure how to access the link which I know is extracted in the file product-image.php.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which image are you talking about ? Product image ?

Comment: Right now it isn't clear how this is a WooCommerce question. To echo Rohil, what image?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough in my question. Yes I was referring to the product image (in full resolution) whereby the user can click to download. If you inspect element on the image in this particular example, the link is http://snshpl.com.sg/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/8003.jpg and I want this to tag to the download button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on the single product page, you can add the featured image url to your custom button with `wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );`

In your example:

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_meta_end','disclaimer');

function disclaimer(){
    echo '<br /><br /><a href="'.wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ).'" class="single_add_to_cart_button button     
    alt">Download</a><p id="disclaimer-text"><br /><br />*Color Disclaimer: 
    Due to the limitations of desktop scanners and the relative 
    inconsistencies of various display monitors, the colors you see on your 
    screen may not be a totally accurate reproduction of the actual product. 
    We strive to make our colors as accurate as possible, but screen images 
    are intended as a guide only and should not be regarded as absolutely 
    correct. If you would like to see a sample of any product shown on our 
    site, please call Customer Service at 6365 3383 or visit our contact 
    page.</p>';
}
```