# Woocommerce: How to set auto download product image?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

How can I set `auto download product images` when clicking it?

I mean when user clicks on product image to view, then in background image should be automatically download...

(Same should be applied to each product images)

Thank you

Comment: Are you talking about when you click on a single product template feature image?

Comment: You can use this previous article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408146/href-image-link-download-on-click

Comment: <a href="/path/to/image" download><img src="/path/to/image" /></a>

Comment: can you share me php code for it, so that I can use in my theme functions.php  @Andrew schultz

Comment: I have tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118742/woocommerce-creating-a-download-link-to-product-image    but it only downloads first image

Comment: Clarify what you mean by the first image?

Comment: I.e., featured image